# django database design when you will have too many rows

Tags: sql, django, database

I have a django web app with postgres db; the general operation is that every day I have an array of values that need to be stored in one of the tables.
There is no foreseeable need to query the values of the array but need to be able to plot the values for a specific day.
The problem is that this array is pretty big and if I were to store it in the db, I'd have 60 million rows per year but if I store each row as a blob object, I'd have 60 thousand rows per year.

Is is a good decision to use a blob object to reduce table size when you do not want to query with the row of values?
Here are the two options:

**option1**: keeping all

```
group(foreignkey)| parent(foreignkey) | pos(int) | length(int)
  A              |  B                 |  232     |  45
  A              |  B                 |  233     |  45
  A              |  B                 |  234     |  45
  A              |  B                 |  233     |  46
...
```

**option2**: collapsing the array into a blob:

```
group(fk)| parent(fk) | mean_len(float)| values(blob)
  A      |  B         |    45          |[(pos=232, len=45),...]
...
```

so I do NOT want to query pos or length but I want to query group or parent.
An example of read query that I'm talking about is:

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "group"
ON ( "group"."id" = "grouptable"."id" )
ORDER BY "pos" DESC LIMIT 100
```

which is a typical django admin list_view page main query.

Comment: If there's really no need to query the data (using sql) then yeah, just store a blob

Comment: On the other hand — what are benefits of such grouping? If a table is done correctly (indexes, etc) then there theoretically should be no serious difference in performance. If it's done incorrectly, then normalized form should lead to discovering the issue faster. (Through I may be wrong, I haven't done this in practice. Just pure theory.)

Comment: It would be helpful to have some performance plots for growing rows but I could not find any. I shall try to mock large data to see what happens.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve] including explaining "it crashes".

Answer (score 0):

I tried loading the data and tried displaying the table in the django admin page without doing any complex query (just a read query).
When I get pass 1.5 millions rows, the admin page freezes. All it takes is a some count query on that table to cause the app to crash so I should definitely either keep the data as a blob or not keep it in the db at all and use the filesystem instead.

[image]

I want to emphasize that I've used django 1.8 as my test bench so this is not a postgres evaluation but rather a system evaluation with django admin and postgres.

Comment: This is an answer. Additional constructive answers are welcome. I've taken the time to describe the scenario, provide schema example and show the performance change.

Comment: Thanks, I see. PS See my comment on the question. Why do you think 60Mrows a year is too big? For what? Why are you "displaying" millions of rows? What is "some count query"? What data is being used for what purposes? You can have multiple tables updated for different purposes. You will get better & more specific answers the clearer & more informative your question.

Comment: I see your point. I've modified my question and answer. My point here is focused on django and is not a general database evaluation.